# Why doesn't Ramanujan summation converge for the geometric series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, divergent-series

I wanted to verify that

$$ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} +\cdots  = 1 $$

Using Ramanujan summation.

Recall that the Ramanujan summation formula is that

$$ f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + \cdots = - \frac{f(0)}{2} + i \int_0^{\infty} \frac{f(is)-f(-is)}{e^{2\pi s} - 1} ds $$

Here was have $f(n) = 2^{-n}$

So the result should show that:

$$ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \cdots  =   -\frac{1}{2}+ i \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{-is}-2^{is}}{e^{2\pi s} - 1} ds$$

I evaluated the RHS in Wolfram Alpha and surprisingly! I do not get an answer of $1$.

See: [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-1%2F2%20%2Bi*%20integral%28%282%5E%28-is%29%20-%202%5E%28is%29%29%2F%28e%5E%282*pi*s%29-1%29%2Cs%2C0%2Cinfinity%29)

Instead I get a result that is very close to $-0.44$ with some change.

Why might this be so? Is it because of internal floating point error on Wolfram's end, or does Ramanujan summation just not sum some convergent series? (And if Ramanujan summation doesn't sum some series: what is the significance of their implied R-sum values?)

Comment: If you use the full Abel-Plana formula, then you get the expected result: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula).

Comment: It seems then that ramanujan summation, can be used for convergent and divergent results Only if integral f(x) dx 0 to infinity can in some numerical OR formal sense be said to equal 0. Or maybe as long integral f(x) dx from 0 to infinity IS well defined then ramanujan summation fails

Comment: no saying it works if the integral is not well defined is False, since Ramanujan summation says that 1+2+2^2+2^3+... != -1 and integral 2^x dx from 0 to infinity, is clearly not well defined.  So the R-summation will fail for any series whose function's integral cannot be formally said to equal 0

Answer (score 2):

As secavara pointed out one can look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula#See_also) formula which tells us that

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n) = \frac{1}{2}f(0) + \int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx + i \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(it) - f(-it)}{e^{2\pi t} - 1} dt$$

Plugging in our desired values gives us the expected result of 1 as per Wolfram alpha [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-1%2F2%20%2Bi*%20integral%28%282%5E%28-is%29%20-%202%5E%28is%29%29%2F%28e%5E%282*pi*s%29-1%29%2Cs%2C0%2Cinfinity%29%20%2B%20integral%282%5E%28-s%29%2C%20s%3D0%20to%20infinity%29)

Ramanujan's Summation technique is only valid in a range of $f(n)$ whose sums DIVERGE but don't grow as fast as an exponential such as $f(n) = 2^n$. In particular Ramanujan's summation technique is attempting to evaluate the constant

$$  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n) -  \int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx  $$

More generally Ramanujan's summation technique can be seen as trying to extract the constant term from the asymptotic expansion of

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} f(n) - \int_0^{x} f(x) dx $$